Сhanging borders of shared polygon shapefile features in QGIS
In QGIS 3, I have a polygon shapefile where each feature is the border of a region, with shared borders for each adjacent region. I need to change the border of a particular region, but I need the borders of the adjacent regions to move along with the border of the region being changed. How would I go about doing this?

Enable topological editing in the snapping toolbar. Then you can move nodes of adjacent lines together.

old but relevant https://youtu.be/D0Z8vcxiERE?si=Z9yVK_1dDuUxaI9W&t=83
